# How do I "fix affinity key backups in cache configuration"?

Tags: backup, ignite

I have a multi-node Ignite cluster. With 1.7.0 version of Ignite.

Was just hit with this error causing my whole ignite cluster to fail to
startup:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Affinity key backups mismatch (fix
affinity key backups in cache configuration or set
-DIGNITE_SKIP_CONFIGURATION_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=true system property)
[cacheName=ignite-atomics-sys-cache, localAffinityKeyBackups=1,
remoteAffinityKeyBackups=0, rmtNodeId=d663345e-x7ba-5c85-6144-1234a7d3f721]
        at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.checkAttributeMismatch(GridCacheUtils.java:1144)
~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.checkCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:2915)
~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onKernalStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:756)
~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:930)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1739)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1589)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1042)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:569)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:516)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:322)
[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
```

What does it mean by "fix affinity key backups in cache configuration" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that different nodes have different number of backups configured for atomic data structures. This is done via `AtomicConfiguration#backups` property and you need to make sure that value for this property is equal on all nodes.

Comment: I mean yeah that's the consensus we got from everyone. But that shouldn't have happened. we have a 6 node cluster and the nodes definitely have the same configuration on all 6 nodes (it's hard coded in a jar file, and we checked that jar file is definitely up to date). But we do use zookeeper to store dynamic discovery data (so that nodes can communicate to each other). Could that somehow do it?